# Post method in function not retrieve database value in chrome, but worked in firefox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

When I select month from dropdown it will retrieve value from database. 
Successfully got in Firefox but not working in Google chrome and IE

Dropdown:

```
    <select id="classical" name="classical">
        <option value="1" onclick="chagePack('<?php echo sha1('month1')?>',1,1);">1 months</option>
        <option value="2" onclick="chagePack('<?php echo sha1('month3')?>',3,1);">3 months</option>
        <option value="3" onclick="chagePack('<?php echo sha1('month6')?>',6,1);">6 months</option>
    </select>
```

Script:

```
function chagePack(pack,month,type) 
{    
    $.post("change_membership_page",
    {
        pack: pack, month: month, type:type
    },
    function(data, status){
         $("[id='replace-month-pack']").html(data); 
        //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: see a console what error it throws

Comment: It doesn't shows error

Comment: I thing I Used Valid Html only

Comment: Now I received this error,  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined